# Logstash 5.2.1: no config files found

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am trying to run logstash on **Windows**, but keep receiving error messages.

I have a config file (logstash.conf) located at D:\elk\logstash-5.2.1\
When I ran **bin\logstash -f logstash.conf** from D:\elk\logstash-5.2.1, it showed the following error message:

```
10:38:19.617 [LogStash::Runner] INFO  logstash.agent - No config files found 
in path {:path=>"D:/elk/logstash-5.2.1/logstash.conf"}

10:38:19.625 [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - failed to fetch 
pipeline configuration {:message=>"No config files found: logstash.conf. Can 
you make sure this path is a logstash config file?"}
```

When I specified the full path (aka **bin\logstash -f "D:\elk\logstash-5.2.1\logstash.conf"**), the followings showed up:

```
10:47:44.621 [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - failed to fetch 
pipeline configuration {:message=>"No config files found: 
D:\\elk\\logstash-5.2.1\\logstash.conf. 
Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?"}
```

(I also tried using slash instead of backslash, with and without the double quote for path, still didn't work)

The strange thing is that when I run logstash on other machine (with exact ELK configuration), Logstash run smoothly.

I have been doing a lot of research but could not find any solution, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

place your config file in the bin directory under logstash.
for example:/elk/logstash/bin/logstash.config

then run

./bin/logstash -f logstash.conf

Comment: I encountered the same issue . I feel windows has a lot of problem running the elk :(